# DirectoryInfo Create() method doesn't need directory path passed?

Tags: c#, .net

How does `DirectoryInfo` know where to create new directory if the one I declared doesn't exist or gets changed? Because `Create()` method doesn't take parameters.

Like, `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)`, where path is passed. So, would `DirectoryInfo.Create()` and `Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\users\\Desktop")` do the same thing... using `C:\\users\\Desktop` as the path.

Answer (score 6):

`DirectoryInfo` isnt used as a static. You pass the path into the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when initializing it.

The create method will then create the path used in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but an instance of `DirectoryInfo` represents a *specific* directory -- existing or not -- at a certain path.  Calling `Create()` just creates the directory in the file system it if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: ok, I guess I needed to know the difference between the two, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize a DirectoryInfo object and pass in the directory path at that time

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyPath");
di.CreateDirectory();
```